# Hot questions script gone wild!

Tags: support

I have been looking at this for few days, and I think the hot questions shown on https://askubuntu.com/?tab=hot are totally wrong.

Today, I saw this list
[image]

the first one(hottest) is with 0 votes, 0 answers and 12 views, with activity 41 mins ago by avinash raj. I feel that the "patch openssl.." question with 1 vote, 2 answers and 91 views and activity 2 hours agomust be hotter.

The above suggestion maybe questioned, but what is the "shell script, a good example..." question with -3 votes doing in this list?

So I seriously think the script behind this is broken, can a SE employee or mod ensure this?

**EDIT:** far below I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/444702/184942) question which should be much up on the list.

Comment: These are active questions.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no they aren't

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at currently hot questions which were recently asked. If you switch to the tab named "Week", it would list hot questions asked within the past week. That [OpenSSL question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444702/how-to-patch-cve-2014-0160-in-openssl) is right at the top in the Weekly list.

[image: top questions tab]

Similarly, if you switch to the tab named "Month", it lists hot questions asked within the past month. <sub>(Where you can find [my question about `/dev/null`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435887/i-can-read-from-dev-null-how-to-fix-it) sitting at the top at the moment. YAY)</sub>

Comment: I know that, but why is -3 voted question sitting in that list? It should be on `coldest` question list.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Hotness is calculated based on the formula given in [this MSO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/205516).

Comment: According to that formula, a question with negative votes will have negative score and thus it should not come in 8th position on hot questions list(unless all recent questions are downvoted, which is not the case in the image).